# Auto complete processing Orders after x minutes or hours in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, scheduled-tasks, orders

based on *[Automatically cancel order after X days if no payment in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792360/automatically-cancel-order-after-x-days-if-no-payment-in-woocommerce/55793020#55793020)* answer code, I have make some changes trying to autocomplete paid orders  after x Minutes *(or x hours)*:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'hourly_update_status_orders', 10, 4 );
function hourly_update_status_orders( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
    // Set Your shop time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    // Enable the process to be executed daily
    if( in_array( $new_status, array('processing') )
        && get_option( 'paid_orders_hourly_process' ) < time() ) :
    
        $time_delay       = 60 * 5; // <=== SET the time delay (here 1 hour)
        $current_time     = strtotime(str_replace(':','-', date('Y-m-d h:i:s') ));
        $targeted_time    = $current_time - $time_delay;

    // Get paid orders (10 mints old)
    $paid_orders = (array) wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'        => -1,
        'status'       => 'processing',
        'date_created' => '<' . $targeted_time,
        'return' => 'ids',
    ) );

    if ( sizeof($paid_orders) > 0 ) {
        $completed_text = __("The order is Completed.", "woocommerce");

        // Loop through WC_Order Objects
        foreach ( $paid_orders as $paid_order ) {
            $order->update_status( 'completed', $complted_text );
        }
    }
    // Schedule the process to the next day (executed once restriction)
    update_option( 'paid_orders_hourly_process', $current_time + $time_delay );

    endif;
}
```

I can only make it work for a daily change, but not for an hourly change…

Could someone help me to check where I am wrong?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:processing] tag. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Those solutions are really not made and not very effective for an hourly delay (or less) as the code is triggered when a new order is made (or when admin make a manual change on an order status.

Now there are some mistakes in your code, try the following instead *(untested)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'hourly_update_status_orders', 10, 4 );
function hourly_update_status_orders( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
    // Set Your shop time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

    // Enable the process to be executed daily
    if( in_array( $new_status, array('processing') )
        && get_option( 'paid_orders_hourly_process' ) < time() ) :

    $time_delay       = 60 * 60; // <=== SET the time delay (here 1 hour)
    $current_time     = strtotime( date('Y-m-d H:00:00') );
    $targeted_time    = $current_time - $time_delay;

    // Get paid orders (10 mints old)
    $paid_orders = (array) wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'        => -1,
        'status'       => 'processing',
        'date_created' => '<' . $targeted_time,
        'return' => 'ids',
    ) );

    if ( sizeof($paid_orders) > 0 ) {
        $completed_text = __("The order is Completed.", "woocommerce");

        // Loop through WC_Order Objects
        foreach ( $paid_orders as $paid_order ) {
            $order->update_status( 'completed', $complted_text );
        }
    }
    // Schedule the process to the next day (executed once restriction)
    update_option( 'paid_orders_hourly_process', $current_time + $time_delay );

    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

---

**If you use minutes** instead of hours, you should change:

```
$current_time     = strtotime( date('Y-m-d H:00:00') );
```

to:

```
$current_time     = strtotime( date('Y-m-d H:i:00') );
```

---

> #### Final note - A better alternative.
>
> **Is better to use something else like the free plugin [Action scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/)** made by Automatic *(the owners of WordPress and WooCommerce)* that is a robust scheduling library already included and used by WooCommerce and the plugin Subscriptions.
>
> You can use it in any code and it's a much better alternative than anything else.
>
> Here is the documentation usage: https://actionscheduler.org/usage/

Comment: thank you for updating my code. I have tried yours, now order status is not changing from processing to complete. Even code is there to update the status.

Answer (score 0):

Now i am using this code its look more efficient then previous. but still having interval problem. when status change from processing to complete no interval between them.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ) return;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $time_order     = strtotime($order->get_date_created()->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $time_current   = time();
    $time_interval  = $time_current - $time_order;

    //Case refresh page after 3 hours at order, no changed status
    if( $order->get_status() == 'processing' && $time_interval < 18000 ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```